# Can I max out all retirement account types?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, roth-ira, roth-401k

Hypothetically speaking, could I contribute the maximum to a 401k, a Roth 401k, an IRA, and a Roth IRA?

That would be a total of 46k per year (17.5k + 17.5k + 5.5k + 5.5k).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most that you could contribute would be maxing out a 401k (of either type) and a Roth IRA.

17.5 + 5.5 = 23k (assuming you aren't old enough for the 401k catch up provision)

The 401k contribution limits are regardless of Roth or traditional 401k.

If you contribute to a workplace 401k it will phase out your deduction for a traditional IRA.

That leaves the Roth IRA as your other option.

If you are married and your spouse works, you can contribute 46k (17.5 his 401k, 17.5 her 401k, 5.5 his roth ira, 5.5 her roth ira).

If you are married and your spouse does not work, you can contribute 28.5k (17.5 his 401k, 5.5 his roth ira, 5.5 her spousal roth ira).

*Note:  Some would say that maxing out a Roth 401k at 17.5k is more than maxing out a traditional 401k at 17.5 because a Roth 401k takes more than 17.5k of earnings to contribute 17.5k of funds and a traditional 401k takes 17.5k of earnings to contribute 17.5k of funds.*

Comment: Your 4th line needs clarification, a 401(k) at work creates an IRA deduction phaseout, not an automatic elimination.

Comment: Also, Roth is a name, not acronym, I'm pretty excited about Roths myself, but all caps looks like shouting.

Comment: Also worth noting that, even without a 401k, the IRA contribution limit is for Traditional and Roth combined.

Comment: Thanks @JoeTaxpayer   I forget that Roth is a name. :)  I also updated the phaseout line.

Comment: Good job! Easy stuff to miss.

Comment: Roth IRA contributions are also subject to phaseout, though at income levels much larger than the phaseouts for Traditional IRAs. But there is a difference: the phaseout for Traditional IRAs is the phaseout of the _tax-deductability;_ one is still entitled to _make_ a contribution to a Traditional IRA but the contribution cannot be _deducted_ (in part or wholly) from current income. (The later distribution of these amounts is not taxable income). On the other hand, MFJ taxpayers with MAGI > 188K are _prohibited_ from making _any_ contribution whatsoever to a Roth IRA.

Comment: What about employer's match? Self-employed can put much more in the 401k as well. IRA deduction is phasing out, but you can still contribute to the IRA. Roth IRA however is limited by income (you can use loophole though).

Comment: "If you contribute to a workplace 401k it will phase out your deduction for a traditional IRA." Whether you contribute is completely irrelevant. It just matters whether you were *covered* by an employer retirement plan, i.e. whether one was offered to you to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can't stack traditional and Roth versions of a retirement account.  The contribution limits apply to the sum of traditional + Roth.

That being said, you get a bigger effective contribution with the Roth version as with the traditional some of the money will be used for tax, with the Roth money outside the account is used to pay the tax.

Thus your max is Roth 401k + Roth IRA.